# UTF-8 with mysql and php in freebsd swedish chars (åäö)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, freebsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Hi I recently switched from linux to freebsb on my server, and now my database is acting up.

When I try to echo a string containing å,ä or ö (swedish letters) it becomes a questionmark. ie: Söndag becomes S�ndag.
echo "ä"; works.
    $ file --mime test.php
    test.php: text/plain; charset=utf-8

**test.php**

```
<?php
$a="å";
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ":-)");
mysql_select_db("lidev");

$result=mysql_query("select * from DLG where dag='Onsdag'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['dagens'];
echo "<br>";
echo mb_detect_encoding($row['dagens']);
?>
```

mb_detect_encoding() outputs "UTF-8"
My mysql table is in **utf8_general_ci**.

I'm completely stuck! What's wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: If you write `echo "ä";` in a php file, and it comes out as `�`, then you didn't **save the file as UTF-8**. Is this the case?

Comment: You need to put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
` in the php files you are using `echo` in

Comment: withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8;')

Answer (score 3):

seems like you're not using utf-8 *everywhere* so your data got messed up at some point. depending on what exactly you're doing, you'll have to change/add one or more of the following points (most likely it's the `SET CHARSET`/`mysql_set_charset` you forgot):

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this after opening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn); // when using the mysql_-functions
  > mysqli::set_charset('utf8') // when using mysqli
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Comment: why in the hell post a duplicate answer???

Comment: when i started writing this, there was no "close as duplicate"-vote and i won't delete an answer just because i recognise this later, as it might still be helpful. indeed, you're right: this question is a duplicate and that's why i also voted to close it.