# Problems with swedish letters MySQL and LAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I have struggled with this some time. I could not get it to work.

On the url http://course.easec.se/problem.pdf I have put together what I have done so far!

Any suggestions?

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');  //no changes
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_test4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
echo "From PHP Script  ååååå\n";   //to see if there is problem when edit the script
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_tbl";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "Kundid: " . $row["kund_id"]. " - Förnamn: " . $row["fnamn"]. " - Efternamn: " . $row["enamn"]. " - Adress:" . $row["adress1"] ."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();   
?>
```

Client:

[image: Client]

[image]

[image]

It works now, seems do be my editor, when I tried ANSI instead of UTF-8 and Changes the header to !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVBXj.png)

Comment: This is not an acceptable question.  Please format it and include all relevant information directly in the question.  That PDF can (and probably will) break at some point.

Comment: if you're getting/outputting UTF from the database, why are you telling the browser to expect iso8859 text? "I'm going to be sending you a banana" and then throw a watermelon .

Answer (score 3):

Directly below

`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

add

`$conn->set_charset("utf8");`

Note: In addition you should also make sure that the charset of your HTML (in the `<head>` tag) is set to `utf-8`, like `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: almost, that should be `utf8mb4`

Comment: @Martin I don't think so - the basic letters of languages like Swedish, German etc. (at least all Western European ones) are all included in utf8, and that's what the OP needs

Comment: It's more through luck that OPs content would still work in this case, but `utf8` shouldn't be encouraged as it's only 3bits. why offer a third of a character set when the full character set can be offered?

Comment: if emojis are involved, yes, but if it's just "real language", it doesn't matter - utf8 will work. But of course: Why not offer more and use the same little part of it.

Comment: You mean emojis such as the `£` Stirling symbol or the `€` euro symbol or the `-` dash symbol when entered into UTF-8 HTML page inputs and saved to the Db etc. etc.

Comment: @Martin No, these are part uf utf8, otherwise my websites wouldn't work properly. Just because they aren't on every keyboard, it doesn't mean they aren't included in utf8

Comment: it's nothing to do with keyboard, these characters get saved and output in `utf8_` charset mysql as two jumbled other characters. I've seen this numerous times, it's not a maybe. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Use:** 
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');`

**Instead of:** 
`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

> No need to use inside while loop, use top of the page before print anything.

Comment: No changes, sorry!  /Mats

Comment: Will you try again by removing `mysqli_set_charset("utf8");` if not work then  again try with  `mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'ISO-8859-1');`

Comment: It was the same problem, I found this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120774/utf-8-with-mysql-and-php-in-freebsd-swedish-chars-%c3%a5%c3%a4%c3%b6

Comment: And I did all the steps, but no luck, then as a last effort I change editor to ANSI instead of UTF-8 then it works! I have a site on Azure and work with notepad as a editor, I Always use UTF-8. But your suggestion work, if you use UTF-8 it does not!

Answer (score 0):

I like how you set your question in a PDF, somewhat original `:-D` . Now, the answer to your problem will be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Read the whole question and as many of the answers as you can.

> then as a last effort I change editor to ANSI instead of UTF-8 then it works!

Due to this the issue is your internal PHP script encoding so Reaseach using PHP [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) and setting your PHP code to :

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); //this is the important one! 
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
```

to ensure your PHP code is also UTF-8 complient when executed. You can also (or should be able to) edit the settings in your IDE editor to save PHP files without UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) which will also solve this problem and save them as UTF-8 understandable by other services.

---

Additional Notes (cos I like to moan about MySQL UTF-8):

MySQL `UTF-8` is **NOT the full UTF-8** . Solutions are offered in the linked thread above, some general additions:

- 1) You want to always use `UTF8mb4` (and ideally `_unicode_ci`).
- 2) In the final screenshot of your PDF you should to set as many of these as practical to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
- 3) Setting the *connection* character set is vital, even if the server and the client both use `utf8mb4` if the connection is only `utf-8` it brings everything else down to that low point.
- 4) Recommended:

  ```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');  //UTF-8
  ```

Only MySQL UTF-8 is broken, other implementatios of it is not and is perfectly usable as and is generally regarded as an HTML standard.